# Is there a popcount() for both Simulator and iOS device?

Tags: ios, iphone

The closest thing I can find is `T popcount(T x)` in the [Metal Standard Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MetalShadingLanguageGuide/std-lib/std-lib.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014364-CH5-SW1).

Is there a simpler version, like:

```
#include <x86intrin.h> 
__builtin_popcount();
```

which compiles well for the Simulator but not for the iPhone device ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `#include <x86intrin.h>`:

```
// #include <x86intrin.h> 
__builtin_popcount();
```